Python FastAPI endpoint receiving only single file when client (Postman) sends multiple files
I have this endpoint function definition in Python FastAPI
@router.post("/process_files")
async def process_files(files: Optional[Union[UploadFile, List[UploadFile]]] = File(None)):
    print(f"\nFiles: [{files}]")
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"status": "completed", "message": "all files processed"})

It is supposed to receive multiple files. However when I send multiple files via Postman it seems receiving only one file. For example when I send my_file1.pdf and my_file1.pdf the print output is like this indicating it has received only my_file2.pdf

Files: [UploadFile(filename='my_file2.pdf', size=92838,
headers=Headers({'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="files";
filename="my_file2.pdf"', 'content-type': 'application/pdf'}))]

How to receive multiple files in Python FastAPI?

I would try using just files: List[UploadFile], it might be that FastAPI is not parsing the Union correctly.

@M.O. That works. But things start getting messy when we want to make it Optional

files: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = None works great for me?
